# docker compose: postgresql create db, user pass and grant permission

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, archlinux

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./django_httpd_mod_wsgi
    ports:
     - "8000:80"
  db:
    build:
      context: ./postgresql
    volumes:
       - db-data:/var/lib/postgres/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

I am building postgresql image using archlinux:

The following is my postgresql Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux/base

RUN yes | pacman -S postgresql

RUN mkdir /run/postgresql/
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /run/postgresql/

USER postgres

RUN initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data

RUN psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE btgapp;' 
RUN psql -c "CREATE USER simha WITH PASSWORD 'krishna';" 
RUN psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE btgapp TO simha;'

CMD ["/usr/bin/postgres","-D","/var/lib/postgres/data"]
```

When I try to do:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get the error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE dbname;'' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I understood that I have to run the `psql -c CREATE DATABASE "dbname"` after starting the postgresql server by `/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgres/data`

But I cannot start multiple commands in a Dockerfile. So how to do this?

The option is to start a script, but then it will be difficult to see postgres running as a single process.

Comment: Any particular reason that you are not using the official postgres image? It supports this type of behaviour on startup.

Comment: I want to try with archlinux. Because I am using the same os for all my web and redis also. It will save space also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the comments, I will try to answer here.

I believe that you should go with the postgres 11-alpine image. And I will try to explain why here.

Official docker images come with a number of benefits that you should always consider before starting your own.

1. **Upgrade path is easy** - when a new revision of the application wrapped in the image is released, the official docker image will in most cases be updated along with it. And ususally the changes respect the configuration conventions that the image has established. Such as environment variables, startup specifics. So that users can simple change the tag in their stacks, and upgrade. There may of course be breaking changes - always check this.
2. **Large user base** - when images like postgres have been downloaded more than 10 milliion times (2019), this does not only mean that it is popular, but inherently works like a guarantee that the image has been tested thoroughly. Any elementary bugs have been weeded out already, and you will have an easy time with the image.
3. **Optimized for size and performance** - you can be sure that attention has been paid to a lot of details, minimizing the size of the image and maximizing performance. Many projects publish their applications on a few different linux distros. Like postgres - they publish `debian` and a `alpine` based images. The `alpine` image is the smaller one, while the `debian` is slightly larger, but gives you access to the vast debian package repositories if you need extra packages installed.
4. **Easy configuration** - maintainers of the official images usually understand that usecases of their userbase very well. And they try to make our lives as developers and admins easier (god bless them). Official images usually have some pretty good documentation sitting right on their docker hub landing page, or a link to a github repo where the `README.md` will cover common usecases. I find that these instructions are worth a good read from top to bottom.

I understand that you want to keep the image small, but what do you know - the postgres project has got your usecase covered.

The latest alpine postgres image tagged `11-alpine` has a compressed footprint of **28 MB** and decompressed of **70MB**. While the `archlinux/base` image that you want to start off with has compressed base footprint of **153MB** and a decompressed size of **445MB**. And that's before you introduce postgres itself.

Add to that, that the database and user that you want created on startup - can be handled in the environment variables alone for the official postgres image. Like this:

```sh
docker run -d --name some-postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=simha \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=btgapp \
postgres:11-alpine
```

If that does not cover the initialization that you need for your database, then you can copy `.sql` scripts (and `.sh` scripts) into a special location in the image - and they will be executed on startup. For this you can extend their image like this:

**`init-user-db.sh`**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER simha;
    CREATE DATABASE btgapp;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE btgapp TO simha;
EOSQL
```

And then with a `Dockerfile` like this:

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine
COPY ./init-user-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
```

(This is taken from [the postgres description on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres?tab=description))

In closing - I would recommend that you do not prioritize the distro that an image is based on over the usability and maintainability. Docker enables us to run applications in containers without really caring too much about what distro is inside the container. It's all linux anyway. At the end of the day, I expect that you want a stable postgres database container like me. This is what I get with the official postgres image.

I hope I helped you evaluate your options on this.

Comment: Thank you very much this explanation. I am fine to shift to the official docker image. But i am also trying to understand how to do it using archlinux. Just to learn. So if i am using Docker compose with multiple containers then i cant use the docker run command for postgresql, Since it has to start before web start. I think in my postgresql Dockerfile i have to try with ENTRYPOINT rather than CMD. Also is there any documentation how postgres:11-alpine Dockerfile is made. Learning to create own Dockerfiles gives us more understanding.

Comment: For the reason of leaning more about Dockerfiles and how docker containers work - it is definitly a good project to create some images of your own like this. Enjoy sir!

Comment: Thank you. I am used to Arch linux  repos, aur and installing packages and nice wiki pages. So i am happy that with the help of docker i can continue with my Arch linux