# Docker does not recognize .env postgres variabls

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

EDIT: Docker does not seem to create my postgres database even though I have them defined in my `.env` file.

I've used `docker-compose config`, and it looks like Docker acknowledges my data:

```
environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: animemusicsorter
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    POSTGRES_USER: waifuszn
```

But when I run `docker-compose up`, I am given these errors:

```
postgres    | 2021-07-12 22:39:01.906 UTC [35] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "waifuszn"
postgres    | 2021-07-12 22:39:01.906 UTC [35] DETAIL:  Role "waifuszn" does not exist.
```

I have tried removing volumes and removing `postgres` and re-creating them but that also has not given me any results.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:11.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
    volumes:
      - ~/srv/docker/template-postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw

  django:
    container_name: django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./conf/django/Dockerfile.windows
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app:rw
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env

  react:
    container_name: react
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./conf/react/Dockerfile
    command: yarn run start:dev
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./front/src:/app/src:rw
      - ./front/public:/app/public:rw
```

Comment: Are you using docker-compose.yml? If you do, can you share it please?

Comment: I'm asking because you also need to pass your env file to your postgres service inside compose.

Comment: Just added it; sorry if the indentation is messed up, the code block was being very difficult. Pretty sure I pass the .env file at the bottom of it though; unless I did it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your Postgres service passes the environment variables:

```
version: "3"

services:
    django:
        build: .
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: django
        command: bash -rc "python intento/manage.py makemigrations &&
                           python intento/manage.py migrate &&
                           gunicorn --limit-request-line 8190 --workers=3
                           --chdir /usr/src/app/src wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        expose:
            - 8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        depends_on:
            - pgdb
    pgdb:
        image: postgres
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: pgdb
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
```

EDIT: Just saw the example you gave, change the = in your Postgres environment properties with :

Comment: Why am I just seeing that LMAO, let's see if it'll work now.

Comment: Maybe you need to rebuild the PostgreSQL container?

Comment: Doing that right now, will probably edit the original question if  this doesn't work. I laerned that environmental variables will only be recognized on initial startup, though, so maybe a full reset is what I need.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work either. Re-worded the original question; hopefully can get a different perspective on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated `.env` file is a good practice for the setting the environment variables for your docker builds.
As per your question/issue :

> I am not sure if I still need to create the database locally on my system, or whether Docker handles it automatically.

You will not have to create a database locally if you are also deploying a postgres container using docker-compose. If that's the case i would recommend that you attach both these container to a network of your choice and name the container so that the use of host name as `postgres` can be reached by django container.
The `.env` file can be selectively provided to the container(probably your indentation shifted while pasting your docker-compose file) and the following `docker-compose.yml` file should look like this

```
   version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:11.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
    volumes:
      - ~/srv/docker/template-postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    networks:
      - network_name

 django:
   container_name: django
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./conf/django/Dockerfile.windows
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app:rw
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - network_name

networks:
  network_name:
    name: network_name
```

You might face permission issues for your user, so you might want to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243023/docker-compose-postgresql-create-db-user-pass-and-grant-permission) issue that can guide you to create a `Dockerfile` for your database.

Answer (score 0):

When you first run `docker-compose up`, [Postgres will initialize the DB](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/5c0e796bb660f0ae42ae8bf084470f13417b8d63/11/stretch/docker-entrypoint.sh#L67) with the configured `POSTGRES_*` variables.

After that, if you changed one of these variables you need to manually reset them to the DB too via `psql` or execute `docker-compose rm postgres; docker-compose up postgres` to recreate the DB with new variables.

WARNING: `docker-compose rm postgres` will drop your current DB.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232883/5274713) recommends `docker-compose down -v` to wipe your volume either.